# specify type of array in an object (typescript)

Tags: typescript

I know how to declare the type in a variable.

```
let members: string[] = []    // this works perfectly
```

I want to have an array of strings in an object.
How can I format it correctly?

```
const team = {
   name: String,
   members<string[]>: [],   // this gives error!!
}
```

The solution

```
const team = {
   name: String,
   members: [] as string[]
}
```

Comment: Specifying the whole object type is possible (but a bit verbose). Asserting the type of a particular property with `as` is possible, but is ugly, I hope there's a better way

Comment: The typo was not the problem for the error. How would you describe a string array in an object using the "as"?

Comment: `members: [] as string[]`

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was looking for this one. ```members: [] as string[]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to specify the type of the whole object, just like you're doing with `members` - put the type of the object after a colon, before the `=` assignment:

```
const team: {
  name: StringConstructor;
  members: string[];
} = {
  name: String,
  members: [],
};
```

Another way is to assert the type of only the property in question with `as` (but I don't like this approach because I prefer to only use `as` to indicate to TypeScript something that there's no way of annotating otherwise).

```
const team = {
  name: String,
  members: [] as string[],
};
```